# Make sidebar height 100% of the browser window

Tags: html, css

I have a issue with the left sidebar.

I would like to make the left sidebar 100% height of the browser always no matter what content is there in right hand panel.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="leftwrapper">Some text</div>
    <div class="rightwrapper">Some text for right</div>
</div>
```

Fiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/32uppbhy/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Percentage heights are relative, you want the containing element `.container` to stretch the full height of the viewport, so it needs a height of 100%, but 100% of what? So you also need to set it on your `html` and `body` elements. Then simply give your absolutely positioned sidebar `bottom:0;` to stretch it the full height.

Simply change your CSS thus:

```
html, body { /* ensure the available document space is the full height of the viewport */
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height:100%; /* <-- make the containing element full height */
}
.leftwrapper {
    background-color: #0b7582;
    bottom: 0;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    width: 8%;
    bottom:0; /* <-- anchor the element to both the top and the bottom of the viewport */
}
.rightwrapper {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 8%;
    width: 92%;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for explaining the height thing.Accepted :)

Comment: This is correct, keep in mind though that float doesn't work on an absolute positioned element.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following rule to the top of your CSS:

```
html, body, .container, .leftwrapper {height:100%;}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help.It's just one liner code.

Comment: No worries, happy to help - I like to keep things as simple as humanly possible ;o)

Answer (score 3):

Few elements derive their height from **body** and **html** tags as their ***parent***. What you can do is simply create a new css rule for body and html tag with a **height** property of **100**% and then another rule for your ***sidebar height to be 100%***. Hope it works :)

CSS rules:

```
html,body{height:100%;}
.sidebar{height:100%;}
```